# How does one build a reduced runtime image

Tags: pharo

I'm a long time VA Smalltalk developer and VA has a pretty extensive dependency mechanism for creating a reduced runtime image. I don't see anything like this in Pharo. I've looked into Metacello but that appears to be more about loading packages into a dev environment. Is there a documented way of doing this in Pharo?

Answer (score 3):

Pharo already occupies a very small size compared to other programming environments: is less than 30m in memory most of the time.

Nevertheless, if you still need a reduced image, you can start for a Pharo-minimal image, which you can dig here: https://ci.inria.fr/pharo/view/4.0-Bootstrap/job/Pharo-4.0-Bootstrap-Step-1.0-Shrink/

The Pharo-minimal image is a reduced image, with just the kernel of the system and a way to load other projects inside. 
You can check out the sibling jobs to see how you can load them, but is basically something like this:

```
./pharo Pharo.image config http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/Pharo/SystemConfigurations/main ConfigurationOfSUnit --group=Core,Tests  --install=stable
```